# Two databases in MYSQL with Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have one database that I specifically using for Django. I ran into a simple problem. For the user authentication in the login I need to use data from another database(mysql) and table. Both the tables are in the same server. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define both the databases in your `settings.py`. You should read through setting up [multiple databases documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/). It's pretty straight forward. Once you have databases configured and synchronized, you can manually select a database for a `QuerySet` as follows:

```
Model.objects.using('database').all()
```

### Update:

To specify a connection for a model you can define a `Router` as follows.

```
from django.db import connections

class MyRouter(object):
    """
    This router object will take care of the database
    operations for models.
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name == db
        return db == default
```

and then for your models in models.py you can do something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    connection_name="filename"
```

### Update#2

you can setup the router anywhere you like. All you need to do is pass the Routers path to the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` variable in the `settings.py` file. For the sake of cleanliness of code and being organised i generally do this in a separate `routers.py` file under my application folder and then set the `DATABASE_ROUTERS`

#### example:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MyRouter',]
```

Comment: Bruh. Got one problem. I won't have model defined for that database. How can I perform the query.!

Comment: Thanks. Where do I define Router, in views.py?